# can crc32 hashing algorithm repeat

Tags: php, crc32

I am trying to encode large file names and store it as small names in database.

So Can I convert string using crc32 and store it in database ?

Can Two different string result in same number.If so what is the probabilty

Comment: a hash can always collide, your question has a huge answer pool (not conducive to the SO model)

Comment: If collides what is the probability of collide between crc32 and others

Comment: first search result for 'has collision probability' http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/ - learn to use search engines, they are the number one location for answers to your broad questions.  Note that SO is not a location to ask these questions, however it is a good location to search for answers.  IOW, search is your friend - much more so than asking questions.